# Does Power Steering Fluid Circulate Through Whole System?

Tags: power-steering, power-steering-fluid

Does all power steering fluid eventually move through the whole P/S system?  In other words, would a drop of new fluid placed in the reservoir eventually get pulled in to system and circulated around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the power steering system is a closed loop system.  See the diagram below for the components of a typical hydraulic power steering system.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Paulster.  I think I got it, i.e. that any given drop of PSF anywhere in the system, including the refill reservoir, will eventually circulate through everywhere, but just so I am clear, where is the PSF reservoir in this diagram?  Is it the same as the pump?

Comment: @mblatz The reservoir isn't shown in the diagram unfortunately.  From my experience, the return pipe goes back to the reservoir and there is a feed from the reservoir to the pump.  So any fluid in the reservoir is circulated through the system.

Comment: OK...I got it, HandyHowie...I appreciate the clarification.  I'll take a look at my system and see if I can identify the lines involved.